# Show that F is continuous with the following property

Tags: calculus, continuity

Let $f:[0,1]$x$[0,1]$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ be continuous and let F:[0,1] $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ with $F(x)=\int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)dy$. Show that F ist continuous. I don't really have an idea, so help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon >0$. You have that $f$ is uniformly continuous, and thus, there is $\delta >0$ s.t. for all $(x,y),(a,b)\in [0,1]\times [0,1]$, $\|(x,y)-(a,b)\|<\delta $ implies that $|f(x,y)-f(a,b)|<\varepsilon $. Let $x\in [0,1]$ and $|h|<\delta $. Then,

$$|F(x+h)-F(x)|\leq \int_0^1|f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)|\,\mathrm d y<\varepsilon .$$
Therefore, $F$ is continuous.